# Return a string if a substring is known

Tags: javascript, string, include, iteration, substring

I want to iterate through an object with object keys. With a single input (substring) from a user, I want to get the whole string to do the iteration.

My object:

```js
const obj = {
  "I am string": "Hello World",
  "I am second": "foo bar"
}
```

If the user types the substring "string", I want to get to the whole string "I am string" and in the other case, if the user types the substring "second" or "am second" I want to have "I am second" and so on...

My goal is to reach the value of the object with the exact string automatically:

```js
obj["I am string"] // "Hello World"
```

Comment: What if you have two keys `"I am string"` and `"I am another string"` and user enters `"string"`. Which key will you use for retrieving output?

Comment: You're right Ajay. In that case I have to handle the output with the .filter()-function to show the user all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to do a [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) of a chosen Object, and return the String of the *first* match - You can then use the return value as the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

```js
const data = {
  "I am string": "Hello World",
  "I am second": "foo bar"
}

function findKey (searchTerm, objToSearch) {
  return Object.keys(objToSearch).find(key => key.includes(searchTerm));  
}

console.log(findKey('string', data));
console.log(findKey('second', data));

console.log(data[findKey('string', data)]);
```

If this is only used for one Object, you can save yourself a parameter and just hard-code your Object name, instead of `objToSearch`

```js
const findKey = (searchTerm) => Object.keys(obj).find(key => key.includes(searchTerm));
```